# Kafka Issues on consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, load-balancing, publish-subscribe

I'm a newbie in Kafka. I had a glance at the Kafka Documentation. It seems that the the message dispatched to a subscribing consumer group is implemented by binding the partition with the consumer instance.

> One important thing we should remember when we work with Apache Kafka is the number of consumers in the same consumer group should be less than or equal the number of partitions in the consumed topic. Otherwise, the exceedable consumers will not be received any messages from the topic.

In a non-prod environment, I didn't config the topic partition. In such case, is there only a single partition in Kafka. And If I start multiple consumers sharing the same group and subscribe them to the topic, would the message always dispatched to the same instance in the group? In other words, I have to partition the topic to get the load-balance feature in consumer group?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right. One partitions cannot be processed in paralell (by one consumer group). You can treat partition as atomic and it cannot be split.

If you configure non-prod and prod env with the same amount of partitions per topic, that should help you to find correct number of conumsers and catch problems before moving to prod.